# Weighted Overlay doesn't work

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, spatial-analyst

I'm using Weighted Overlay from Spatial Analyst Tools in ArcMap to calculate the weights of two raster layers while calculating, the process just works in an area, not the whole area I'm trying to do.

The weights are just calculated in the area of RN Layer, not in the LandCover area.[image: Here's the result of the process]

Comment: Check the coordinate system of the layers. Must be the same.

Comment: What output extent did you specify in the [tool environment settings](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/weighted-overlay.htm#GUID-21792F00-9D90-4FBE-9F68-90F98802B802)?

Comment: It's the same coordinate system in both layers.

Comment: And the extent I specify in environment is the same of LandCover